# Caching REST api using Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, rest, caching, memcached

I have two servers. First server is serving as datacenter which only contains database and REST API by philstrgeon https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver.

This first server is basically working with database, I already implemented database cache http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html.

Second server, contains frontend which is making requests to first api server and displaying results on site to users. EX: http://api.server.com/getuses?key=XXXX

Problem: As Second server is sending many api requests and first server

1. Is not fast server like google.
2. Contains huge amount of data 2000K rows and expecting more.
3. Using multiple MYSQL JOIN query (Almost 5 joins in query).

Second Server taking time:
 << Page rendered in 6.0492 seconds >>

What I have done and what I am expecting.

1. I have already indexed and cached MYSQL of first(api) server properly.
2. No cache enabled on second server.
3. How would I cache api response to second server and will find that there was no change made since last request.
4. Would you suggest using some other idea on database like (redis, mongodb etc)?

Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think if your tables involve join queries of upto 5 tables you should consider using MongoDB  for keeping the associated data asquerying it will be much faster .At the same time you can use Redis to store session data for fast access.

Hope that Helps